# how to configure correct state transfer in pac4j

Tags: java, openid-connect, pac4j

On my quest to implement an OIDC connection with pac4j (on client side)
I have hit another roadblock. It seems that the state transfer via URL is
not working or propery configured:

The auth request:

```
https://authserver.com/mini-sinai/auth?scope=openid profile email&response_type=code&
redirect_uri=https://client.com/jee-pac4j-demo/callback?client_name=MiniSinai&
state=e8e3b77123&nonce=vvDVEE3hv70GLUvDVG5IyaU30S6EJqsAjGHEyuUg_NA&
client_id=9d9a41d95b4907ca13ac60b0568aa3
```

Is returning:

```
302 https://client.com/jee-pac4j-demo/callback?client_name=MiniSinai&
code=TrCQCp02fodz071SdKTXisZseJFcNwWJcFs7z3772tw&state=e8e3b77123
```

But then the client reports this:

```
org.pac4j.oidc.exceptions.OidcMissingSessionStateException: State cannot be determined
    org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.extractor.OidcCredentialsExtractor.lambda$extract$0(OidcCredentialsExtractor.java:118)
    java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.extractor.OidcCredentialsExtractor.extract(OidcCredentialsExtractor.java:118)
    org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getCredentials(BaseClient.java:74)
    org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic.perform(DefaultCallbackLogic.java:83)
    org.pac4j.demo.jee.DemoConfigFactory$MyCallbackLogic.perform(DemoConfigFactory.java:126)
    org.pac4j.jee.filter.CallbackFilter.internalFilter(CallbackFilter.java:63)
    org.pac4j.jee.config.AbstractConfigFilter.doFilter(AbstractConfigFilter.java:92)
```

Which irritates me as the state is present in the callback. (Both services on the the host worked just fine, hence I assume that the state comes from the tomcat-session). Do I have to configure pac4j in a special way in order to allow state transfer via URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated state is sent to the authorize endpoint and saved into the web session.

The retrieved state on the callback URL is compared to the one retrieved from the web session.

The error: "State cannot be determined" is when you are not able to retrieved the saved state from the web session. So you might have an issue with your web session. What do you see for the JSESSIONID cookie on the HTTP requests?

Comment: Yes it was an issue with the session. After the sessions had expired it suddenly worked.  However, I am completely unfamiliar with the term "WebSession" as I do not use spring at all (alt least not explicitly). Is this part of the HttpSession in JEE?

Comment: In pac4j, the `SessionStore` is an abstraction of the "web session". The `JEESessionStore` uses the JEE `HttpSession`.